# d3js - how to filter the array with values and pass in to data?

Tags: d3.js

I am getting data from backend, where some of the values are `0`. I don't want to create the circle for those values.

I understand, I need to use a filter, but I don't have any idea how to use that.

Here is my code:

```
var circles = city.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(function(d) {
                          return d.values //this is a array length 20 how to filter that? i need only with values more than 0
                        })
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 3.5)
                        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                          return x(d.date)
                        })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) {
                          return y(d.temperature)
                        })
                        .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                        .attr("fill", "transparent")
                        .attr("stroke", "yellow")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `d.values` is an array you can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to extract all values different from `0` from it. The following will bind only non-zero values and create circles only for these:

```
.data(function(d) {
    return d.values.filter(function(v) { return v != 0; });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I'm assuming that you meant something more like `.data(dataFromBackend, function (d) { return d.values; })`, otherwise there's no bind!

Anyway, to do what you're describing, and making the assumption that you're not bothered about having the `0`-values in the bind at all, you can simply do:

```
filteredData = backendData.filter(function (d) {
    return d.value != 0;
});
```

There's a detailed reference for `.filter` [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter), but briefly, the function passed to `.filter` is called for every element in `backendData`, with each element referred to by `d` in the usual way. The return value should be boolean (`true` or `false`), but will work with anything, using 'truthiness'. Any element the function returns something 'truthy' for will be included in the final array (`filteredData` in my example), any element the function returned something 'falsey' will not.